# NUnit Testing show a form and populate its textbox from dataset in TestClass

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, nunit, ndbunit

I am new to NUnit, I have written my  and  in a test class for vb.net and it works as follows:

A stored procedure is executed and the result is saved in an xml file with the help of a dataset.
What I need to do now is , Information of this dataset should also be redirected to a textbox in a form so that I can copy this information in clipboard and create dynamic assert statements for instance I want 
  datatable.rows.count,
  datatable.columns.count,
  datatable.columns(i).ColumnName,
  and same to get columnType. All of this info would be shown in the form but I am unable to open a form in NUnit test class. 
Please Reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to split the code which gets the data away from the form and into a separate class.

In your project, create a new class file and put the code which gets the data into there. Then, in your form, call the method which gets the data (which can return a DataSet) so that your form can use it.

In the unit test project, you can then create unit tests against the new class you created. So you don't have to bother with the form at all.

Answer (score 1):

For form testing, considering using [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/) for testing the forms, assuming you are using Windows Forms. You can create the forms and drive mouse movements and clicks, and also query form controls for their content.